# Google Analytics exclude filter not recognizing multiple patterns

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, filtering

I'm trying to exclude my top-level page and certain section pages from a custom report using the exclude filter. It works for a single pattern (i.e. `\news`), but when I try multiple patterns separated by pipes as described [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830) (i.e. `\news|\blog|\catvideos`), none of the patterns are filtered. I would create a filter for each pattern but I need more filters than the maximum allowed by analytics. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I found. Instead of using the "exact" match setting for the filter pattern, I switched to "regex". The regex string to filter the multiple-pattern string in the example above would be `^\/news$|^\/blog$|^\/catvideos$`.

Answer (score -1):

Select "Matching Regex" instead of "containing" while filtration. And then simply enter the pattern you are entering i.e. (*\news|\blog*)